# Magento 2: Remove product title from product page

Tags: magento2

I try following way from `catalog_product_view.xml` but not working I am getting white page.

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="false" />
```

Comment: I think, Your file name is not right. Please share your file location in your theme where you've made these changes.

Comment: i wrote wrong here edited

Comment: The file you've edited is for Product View page not for the Category view.

Comment: do you want to remove category title ?

Comment: you can try <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" /> in catalog_category_view.xml file

Comment: i want remove from product page

Answer (score 0):

I think try this simple way

Go to this path :-

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

And comment the code :-

```
               <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                    <a class="product-item-link"
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                    </a>
                </strong>
```

And override your this file in custom theme :-

```
app/design/frontend/Mycompany/Basic/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

And Comment this code :-

```
<strong class="product name product-item-name">
                    <a class="product-item-link"
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                    </a>
                </strong>
```

I think this best way ...

Hope this help you

Thanks ...